# balls in boxes counting problem

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Mady has an infinite number of balls and empty boxes
available to her. The empty boxes, each capable of holding four
balls, are arranged in a row from left to right. At the first step,
she places a ball in the first box of the row. At each subsequent
step, she places a ball in the first box of the row that still has
room for a ball and empties any previous boxes. How many
balls in total are in the boxes as a result of Mady's 2010th step?

This would involve modular arithmetic but not sure how to solve it. Any idea appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, Mary is counting up in base 5. Example:

```
Right <------------- Left
......00000001 First Step
......00000002 Second Step
......00000003 Third Step
......00000004 Fourth Step
......00000010 Fifth Step
......00000011 Sixth Step
```

So I believe you should find the representation of 2010 in base 5 and add the digits together, e.g. $(2010)_{10} = (31020)_5$ so my answer would be 6 balls.